# visualizing the scatterness of higher dimensional data using python

Tags: machine-learning, python, variance, data-visualization, matplotlib

I have a set of unlabeled data $x \in \mathbb R^n$, and I want to visualize how scattered those points are using python. In dimension 2, we can just use plt.scatter which is quite straightforward. I wonder whether there is any approach to deal with this in higher dimensions.

Comment: What properties of the result interest you? Clearly a monitor can't display data in more than 2 dimensions, so we will, in some way, be forced to make a compromise. Do you wish for the result to be orthogonal? Or preserve pairwise distances? Or something else?

Comment: I am hoping to visualize whether all the points are sufficiently close to a given fixed point  with respect to the Euclidean distances. A good indicator apparently is to directly calculate the average Euclidean distance. However, I do not quite have a good feeling about what the scale should be. So I wonder whether it is possible to have some sort of visualization.

Comment: What, then, do you mean by "sufficiently" close?  That might help answer the question.

Comment: I am not sure about what  threshold to pick, and that is exactly why I need to visualize a bit.

Comment: Hm. If your main interest is the Euclidean distance from a given point, then a simple histogram of these distances may be a good start. Alternatively, you may want to look into [multidimensional scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling), which attempts to project your points into two dimensions while preserving distances as much as possible.